# Mail() - message body with utf-8 and html tags

Tags: php, email, utf-8, email-headers

Contact form on site use script below. It send 2 messages - to me and to the person filling in the form. In second mail I have problem with characters like "ąźćęś"....I would like to use utf-8. I set it in header, but it doesn't work. I need to use in message body html tags also.
What wrong in the code?

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'me@test.com';
$email_subject = "Mail to you";
$email_body = "Hello\n\n"."Test\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone";
$headers = "From: test@test.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

$to2 = "$email_address";
$email_subject2 = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode("Thanks for you message")."?=";
$email_body2 = "Test mail ążźćęśó\n\nBest regards\nTester";
$headers2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";  
$headers2 = 'From: Tester <test@test.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to2,$email_subject2,$email_body2,$headers2);
return true;            
?>
```

Comment: I suggest , use phpmailer or other library.

Comment: As @Rishi mentioned, PHP Mailer is a very good and easy to use library https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer plus it has an example showing exactly how to use it.

Comment: It simple landing page in html. I would like to use this script. Is it possible?